# How can I see the count of fixture entries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a products.yml file with three entries in it which means that my store's front page shows three products which in turn means the test for showing all the products passes because i'm looking for three products. All well and good.

What i'm looking for is the ability to add more products to products.yml without having to update `assert_select '#main .entry', 3` to `assert_select '#main .entry', 4`. Instead i'd like to try something like
`assert_select '#main .entry', products.size` only i haven't been able to find anything, anywhere that provides a way to do that or any examples of people doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
assert_select '#main .entry', Product.count
```

Comment: If i'm interpreting this correctly, inside tests the fixtures are nothing more (or less) than ActiveRecord items. Do i have that right?